# Google PHP $event->getEventStatus() incorrect output

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to check event statuses (google php calendar api), but am getting different results on my local machine as compared to the development/test server.

$eventStatusUrl = $event->getEventStatus();

returns the following locally
    "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.confirmed"

but returns the following on the dev server
    Object id #154
or
    Object id #153

Is Object id #xxx something in php that could be different between the two versions?  Does Object id #xxx mean something specific in php?  Is there another way of getting the status that someone would recommend I use instead of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what do you know, the newer version of php was calling __toString() on its own, while the older version (on the test server) needed some nudging.

```
$eventStatusUrl = $event->getEventStatus()->__toString();
```

That does the trick.